# screen recording with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, desktop-recording

I need to record but only the active window AND without audio: I'm using this command but it records all screen (with application bar)

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 25  -i :0.0+100,200 -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -acodec aac -strict experimental output.mp4
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if you're willing to consider another program.  But `kazam` seemed to work for me.  Maybe you can install it and give it a try if no one else is able to help you with `ffmpeg`?

Comment: I've tried others apps (as SimpleScreenRecorder) but I neet to do it with ffmpeg.....

Answer (score 4):

You can use `xwininfo` to get the co-ordinates of the specific window you want to record.

1. Run `xwininfo`.
2. It will ask you to select the window you want to record.
3. Information about the selected window will appear. The important info is `-geometry` and is probably the last line. Example: `-geometry 1600x900+129+57`
4. Run `ffmpeg` using the numbers from `-geometry`:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size 1600x900 -framerate 50 -i :0.0+129,57 -vf format=yuv420p output.mp4
   ```

Note that x11grab is not "smart". It will only record the area you specify, and it will not follow a window that moves. And if you switch to another desktop that will get recorded too.

Comment: to work on the coordinates id=$(xdotool search --desktop 0 --class  "$name"), where #name is a variable of the window name, eg firefox....   id=$(xdotool search --desktop 0 --class  "firefox"); xdotool getwindowgeometry $id

Comment: with xwininfo I get:   -geometry 1920x1031+0+0

Comment: -i :0.0+1920x1031 doesn't work

Comment: @Lilia Should be `ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size 1920x1030 -framerate 50 -i :0.0 -vf format=yuv420p output.mp4` I adjusted the hight to make it even which is required by the encoder.

Comment: it's ok, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can add this line to your ffmpeg execution code

```
 xdotool selectwindow getwindowgeometry | tr '\n' ' ' | gawk '{print "--video_size " $8 " -i +"$4 }'
```

Or if you want to get the coordinates of the window that has focus :

```
xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowgeometry | tr '\n' ' ' | gawk '{print "--video_size " $8 " -i +"$4 }'
```